# Connecting Celery Worker to Redis in ECS Cluster AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, celery, cluster-computing, amazon-ecs

I'm currently facing a challenge. I'm trying to set up ECS Cluster tasks in my project using Celery and Redis, but I'm encountering connectivity issues between the Celery worker and the Redis server.

In my setup, I've configured the Redis task definition to use the default Redis port. On the Celery worker's container code, I've specified the connection string as redis://redis:6379. However, when I run my worker task, I encounter the following error:

```
[2023-12-18 15:12:46,536: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:6379//: Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known.
```

To troubleshoot, I've ensured that both the Redis server and the Celery worker are hosted on the same VPS. Despite this, the issue persists. I'm wondering if I need to modify the Redis host configuration in some way.

Comment: Is this deployed to EC2 or Fargate? Are the two services running in the same ECS task, or separate ECS tasks? Have you used something like AWS CloudMap or ECS Service Connect to make the `redis` hostname resolvable?

Comment: The tasks are two different tasks for each redis and worker, I will take a look at ECS Service Connect and see if I am able to resolve it.

Comment: It sounds like you have just deployed two ECS tasks, and currently expect the hostname `redis` to magically resolve to the task running the redis server. That's not going to work without actually configuring DNS in your VPC to resolve the `redis` hostname appropriately.